# Hey can someone help me with this assignment in C

Tags: c, arrays

My code is supposed to accept a value for the size of the array and the values from users and then average the cells that are above and to the left of the [i][j] cell including and put it in the [i][j] cell in the summatrix array.
This code compiles and accepts an n value and values accordingly but prints zeros.  I checked if the values are being inserted into the input array by changing the  array in printf from summatrix to input and I get zeros as well.  Is this a problem in the getting the values for the input array?

So I edited the code so instead of %.2lf its %.2f and everything works a search on google showed me that $lf does this kind of thing sometimes.

Comment: Is there anything special about arrays with 78 elements? (In ascii, that is).

Comment: You shouldn't include profanity in your questions. Also, you haven't surrounded anything in curly braces. Your code is going to do all kinds of things that you don't want it to do.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`--> `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

Comment: I have edited the profanity out of the code and description,N is defined as 8 per the assignment requirements sorry I didnt include that part.

Comment: `input['N']['N']` doesn't use the value of the variable or macro `N`. It should be `input[N][N]`.

Comment: this is python indentation, not C, that is what misled you

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your indentation, you are going to want to stick curly braces (`{` and `}`) around your lines of codes as such:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        ncells=i*j;
        sum+=input[i][j];
        avrage=(sum)/(ncells);
        sumatrix[i][j]=avrage;
    }
}
```

This is generally considered good practice to put curly braces around all your conditionals and loops, just to make it explicitly clear what code you are intending to include within the conditional or loop. Only remove the braces when you are absolutely certain the loop or conditional will not contain more than one line.

Comment: it is not considered good coding style, it is a compilation requirement.
it is however considered good coding style to OMIT curly braces around single-argument conditionals and loops

Comment: @Adalcar1 Not in my experience. For example, it is expressly forbidden to do so where I work. But others consider it cleaner, I suppose.

Comment: My bad then, I am still a student, and I thought if our quite strict coding style permitted that, it was probably a general standard

Answer (score 0):

To repeat more "strongly" [DBPriGuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130844/5036612), In C, conditionals such as `for`, `if` and `while` will only affect the next `statement` (single instruction or set surrounded by curly braces).

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        ncells=i*j;
        sum+=input[i][j];
        avrage=(sum)/(ncells);
        sumatrix[i][j]=avrage;
```

is equivalent to (with actual indentation)

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        ncells=i*j;
sum+=input[i][j];
avrage=(sum)/(ncells);
sumatrix[i][j]=avrage;
```

A better way to put it would be

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        ncells=i*j;
        sum+=input[i][j];
        avrage=(sum)/(ncells);
        sumatrix[i][j]=avrage;
    }
```

Comment: It's not called an *instruction*, it's called a *statement*. A block *is* a *statement*.